# JNI code works fine in windows xp but crashes in windows 7

Tags: java, java-native-interface, usb, interrupt

I am using the code provided here: http://www.microchip.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=278617 to transfer data via USB port using Java. It works fine in Windows XP 32bit OS. But when i try to invoke the same interrupt method for sending output report under windows 7 32bit OS environment, JNI crashes Outsite JVM. the crash report can be found here: http://pastebin.com/A9USNFFY

The function causing the JNI crash is given below:

```
    JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_MyHID_IntSendOutputReport(JNIEnv *jEnv, jobject     jObj, jbyteArray outputReport)
       {
    boolean Result = false;
    byte *buffer = new byte[Capabilities.OutputReportByteLength];
    jboolean isCopy = JNI_TRUE;
    buffer = (byte*)jEnv->GetByteArrayElements(outputReport, &isCopy);

    /*
    API Function: WriteFile
    Sends a report to the device.
    Returns: success or failure.
    Requires:
    A device handle returned by CreateFile.
    A buffer that holds the report.
    The Output Report length returned by HidP_GetCaps,
    A variable to hold the number of bytes written.
    */

    DWORD BytesWritten = 0;
    if (WriteHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) Result = WriteFile
                                                        (WriteHandle, 
                                                        buffer, 
                                                        Capabilities.OutputReportByteLength, 
                                                        &BytesWritten, 
                                                        NULL);

    delete buffer;
    return Result;
}
```

So, can anyone please help me finding the issue why JNI is being crashed outside JVM under Windows 7 32bit OS environment? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is completely incorrect. It's hard to believe that it ever ran on any platform. Remove the `new` call and the `delete` line. `buffer` is allocated when you call `GetByteArrayElements()`. If `isCopy` got set to TRUE, you must then call `ReleaseByteArrayElements()` with `buffer` and `JNI_ABORT` as arguments.

You do realize there are Java packages for USB?

Comment: Thanks for responding, @EJP !

Comment: Actually I am new to both in USB and JNI Programming. I found this script while googling over internet and gave it a try. Yes i also came to know about this: http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net/wp/ but in their homepage its saying that the latest version of libusb java is not compatible with this wrapper and the older one has may bugs in windows 7 platform. So i didn't give a try yet.

Comment: also i tried this: http://www.blog.kslemb.com/doku.php/en/projects/globx/java_hid
and was stuck here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906119/access-is-denied-in-interrupt-write-in-jna-implementation-of-usb-hid-communica


If you have any other suggestion about using any other good java packages for USB please do suggest me. and thanks again!

Comment: RXTX is the best I believe. Sun had one called JComm or something but they had to stop supporting Windows in it because MS kept changing the APIs.

Comment: @EPJ- the code should be now like this?

`JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_MyHID_IntSendOutputReport(JNIEnv *jEnv, jobject jObj, jbyteArray outputReport)
{
 boolean Result = false;
 byte *buffer;
 jboolean isCopy = JNI_TRUE;
 buffer = (byte*)jEnv->GetByteArrayElements(outputReport, &isCopy);
  DWORD BytesWritten = 0;
 if (WriteHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) Result = WriteFile
              (WriteHandle, 
              buffer,              Capabilities.OutputReportByteLength,              &BytesWritten,              NULL);
 jEnv->ReleaseByteArrayElements(buffer, JNI_ABORT);
 
 return Result;
}`

Comment: @xihad You missed the part about `if (isCopy)`, but reading the JNI Specification I'm not sure it's important actually.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will notify later on whether it works or not. take care

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tested the modified code and worked like a charm!

Comment: I tried to upvote. but my reputation is still below 15. so couldn't do it. marked the reply as correct instead.